# hash.key(my_key) not accessing keys in nested hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

1- I have little experience in ruby and I am coming from C/Python.

2- In the following snippet:

```
CSV.foreach(filename, quote_char: '"', col_sep: "\t") do |row|
    if header_seen == true
        k = row[primer]
        c = row[counts].to_i
        p = row[prfreq].to_f
        e = row[err].to_f

        print k," ",table.keys," ",table,"\n"

        if table.key(k) == true
            table[k]['counts'] << c
            table[k]['err'] << e
            table[k]['prfreq'] << p
        else
            puts "WHY IT IS ALWAYS GETTING HERE???"
            table[k] = {'counts'=>[c], 
                        'err'=>[e],
                        'prfreq' => [p]
                    }
        end

    elsif header_seen == false and row[0] == "BARCODE"
        counts  = row.index('PRCOUNT')
        primer = row.index('PRIMER')
        prfreq = row.index('PRFREQ')
        err = row.index('ERROR')
        header_seen = true
    end 
end
```

Printing table.keys (line 8), I can see the keys. However, `if table.key(k) == true` never comes true.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `table` is a Hash (which we don't know for sure from your code), `table.key(k)` returns the *value* for the key `k`, if the key exists in your hash, or `nil` if it does not. Since the values of your Hash are seemingly not boolean values, the comparision with `true` will always be false.

If you just want to test, whether the key exists, use the method `key?` instead of `key`:

```
if table.key?(k)
   ...
end
```

(explicit comparision with `true` could be done in this case, but is redundant, so I left it out).

If your Hash  has been constructed to use the standard value for it's default value (i.e. `nil`), you can shorten this to

```
if table[k]
    ...
end
```

The main difference between `table.key(k)` and `table[k]` is that if `k` is missing in the Hash, the former always returns nil, while the latter returns the default value for this particular Hash which you provided in the constructor.

See [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) for details.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `table.key?(k)` instead of `table.key(k)`